# Removed abstract Meta from a Django model class and now child class needs a <model>_ptr field?

Tags: python, django

So originally I had the models structured similarly to this:

```
class Base(models.Model):
    name= models.CharField(max_length=30)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Child(Base):
    other_field = models.CharField(max_length=120)
```

But now, I would like to have both models to have database tables, so I removed the `abstract` field from the Meta class of `Base`

Now when I run `python manage.py makemigrations` from cmd, I'm prompted to enter a default value for `base_ptr` so it can be added to `child`

What is this field? I'm guessing it's something that links the child class to the parent, but I don't know what value it should take as a default.

Comment: This field is the reference from `Child` to its parent `base`. I think however that it will be rather "painful" to make such migration, since it basically means that for each `Child`, you will need to create a `Base` object in the database first. So this is basically a model migration combined with a data migration.

Comment: I think the more "easy" way to do it is, make another pair of `Base`/`Child` models with `abstract = False`, then make a data migration from your old `Base`/`Child` data to the new, and then remove the old. Right now the migration will not be easy.

Comment: Thanks @WillemVanOnsem. So would performing a data migration (as described [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/migrations/#data-migrations)) be the best approach?